# Can Rep(G) tell us whether G is discrete?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, topological-groups, hilbert-spaces, unitary-representations

Given a locally compact group $G$, let $$\mathrm{Rep}(G)$$ be its category of unitary representations.
The objects of that category are strongly continuous unitary representations of $G$ on Hilbert spaces, and the morphisms are $G$-equivariant bounded linear maps.
The operation of tensor product of representations equips $\mathrm{Rep}(G)$ with the structure of a symmetric monoidal category, and there is also a $\dagger$-operation given by sending a $G$-equivariant map to its adjoint.

> Is there a way, given $\mathrm{Rep}(G)$ (given to us as symmetric monoidal $\dagger$-category), to see whether $G$ is discrete?

I.e., is there a property of the symmetric monoidal $\dagger$-category $\mathrm{Rep}(G)$ which is equivalent to $G$ being discrete?

---

For example, $G$ being compact is equivalent to every object of $\mathrm{Rep}(G)$ being a direct sum of simple objects, and all the simple objects being [dualizable](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dualizable%20object).

Comment: A naive question: does this symmetric monoidal dagger category allow us to detect the left regular representation (as an object of the category, up to isomorphism in the category)?

Comment: Almost yes: if we had taken $G$ separable, and if $\mathrm{Rep}(G)$ was the category of reps on separable Hilbert spaces, then the countably infinite direct sum of copies of the regular representations is the unique up to isomorphism absorbing object. That's called Fell's absorption principle. (Here, an object $\Omega$ is called absorbing if for every non-zero object $X$, we have $\Omega\otimes X \simeq \Omega$.) The above separability assumptions are surely just technical annoyances, so I'm confident that the regular rep can be uniquely identified (possibly up to taking direct sums of itself)

Comment: The reason I asked is that discreteness of $G$ can be detected by the Banach-algebra properties of its *Fourier algebra* which can be defined as the set of matrix coefficients of the left regular representation, but I have not thought properly about whether the Fourier algebra and Fourier-Stieltjes algebra can be defined solely in terms of Rep(G) as an abstract SMDcat.

Comment: I would have expected that we can reconstruct $G$ from $\mathrm{Rep}(G)$ (like for similar categories of representations in the context of the Tannaka reconstruction theorem), and then we have an easy answer of course. But is it also the case here?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Yes, absolutely. Do you know how to prove that the fiber functor (the symmetric monoidal functor :Rep()→Hilb which forgets the G-action) is unique up to isomorphism?
)

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg The fact that $G$ is the automorphism group of the forgetful functor $\mathrm{Rep}(G)\to\mathrm{Hilb}$ is proven in the 1979 paper "Duality theorem for locally compact groups and some related topics", by Nobuhiko Tatsuuma.